# How would I create a new document, populate it, and then send it back as json?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I would like to update my API call that creates a new document, to create the new document, populate it, and then return the json response via express.

I have my model set up as follows:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import constants from '../../constants/enums';

const DepartmentBudgetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    department : {
        type : String,
        enum : constants.departments
    },
    owner      : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref  : 'Executive'
    },
    budget     : Number
});

export default mongoose.model('DepartmentBudget', DepartmentBudgetSchema);
```

I have my API calls setup with my express paths, which make a call to my logic, which in turn makes a call to my controller, where I handle all the database work.

My express api call looks like the following:

```
import express from 'express';
import DepartmentsBudgetsLogic from './departmentBudget.logic.js';
import constants from '../../constants/enums';

const router = express.Router();
const code = constants.statusCode;

router.post('/', newDepartmentBudget);

async function newDepartmentBudget( req, res ) {
    try {
        const result = await new DepartmentsBudgetsLogic().newDepartmentBudget(req.body);
        console.log(result);
        res.status(code.created).json(result);
    }
    catch ( error ) {
        console.error('Unable to create department budget.', error);
        res.sendStatus(code.serverError);
    }
}
```

Then my logic function simply calls my controller passing the budget object:

```
import DepartmentBudgetController from './departmentBudget.controller';

export default class DepartmentBudgetLogic {
    newDepartmentBudget( budget ) {
        return new DepartmentBudgetController().newDepartmentBudget(budget);
    }
}
```

Finally, and this is where I think I am having my problem, the controller handles the mongoose work:

```
import DepartmentBudget from './departmentBudget.model';

export default class DepartmentBudgetController {
    newDepartmentBudget( budget ) {
        DepartmentBudget.create(budget).then(function( budget ) {
            return budget.populate('owner').execPopulate();
        });
    }
}
```

The document gets created in the database correctly, but I am really struggling with the code to populate the `owner` field and then return the populated doc as my response.

I know from mongoose's docs that `execPopulate()` returns a promise that resolves to the populated document, but when I console.log the result in my express api call I get "undefined".

I'm still learning here, so I may have overlooked something very obvious.

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Or is there a different direction I should go in so that I can accomplish the overall objective of being able to create a new document, populate it, and then return it in my response object.

Thank you!

Comment: in your async function newDepartmentBudget( req, res ) function, when you console log your result. are you getting anything in the console? console.log(result);

Comment: Yeah, it consoles out as "undefined".

Comment: Which version of mongoose are you using, cause i'm unable to find execPopulate() anywhere in mongoose docs, i know exec().....

Comment: @AfDev It's a document method. Documents have a [populate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) method, but it doesn't get executed unless you call [execPopulate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-execPopulate).